# Export GIMP Settings

Tags: gimp

I've used GIMP for a while and have custom settings, brushes, plugins, etc. installed on my Windows 7 computer. I have a Windows XP machine that I want GIMP on too, and I want all the customizations already on my Windows 7 computer on the XP one as well. Where is the GIMP settings/plugins/brushes folder and what is the best way to transfer everything in a easy manner?

BTW I'm using GIMP 2.8

Comment: Thank you for asking this question because I was searching the ***whole wide web*** to find an answer. Thanks also to the person who answered the question :)

Comment: How is this not off-topic? This should be on SuperUser as per description on the gimp tag itself

Answer (score 3):

#### Your Gimp profile is stored in `C:\Documents and Settings\{USERNAME}\.gimp-{version}\` (on Windows.)

For example, mine is stored at `C:\Documents and Settings\User\james\.gimp-2.8\`.
I also had a leftover `gimp-2.6` folder.

#### Bonus Round: Linux location -

`~/gimp-{version}/`

E.G., `/home/james/.gimp-2.8/`

As for transferring the settings, just copy the folder to a USB stick and put it in the appropriate place on the destination computer.

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @felwithe Since 2013, things have changed quite a bit. In Gimp 2.10 the profile has moved. See [here](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/) to find out where it is (on Windows, somewhere in your `AppData/Roaming` IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

### For all systems & versions:

Everything is in your "Gimp profile"(*). [This tutorial on the Gimp site](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/) shows two ways to figure out where that is, whatever the OS or the Gimp version ("portable" Gimp builds keep the profile elsewhere).

- Executing  `print gimp.directory` in the Python-fu console
- Using `Edit>Preferences>Folders` to locate user folders, that are just below the main Gimp profile directory.

(*) Some files that may require a bit of care:

- `pluginrc` is going to be rebuilt anyway, using the plugins that are actually present on the other system
- `sessionrc` contains windows positions, this may be a problem if the target system has a smaller display (or uses only one display if the source system has several). But you can reset the windows positions to default in `Edit>Preferences>Window management`
- `gimprc` may contain paths to directories that don't exist on the target system, and screen calibration values that can be incorrect on the target system.

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @felwithe What doesn't work? You can't find the profile this way?

Answer (score 1):

Update for Windows 10:

**Your Gimp profile is stored  in  (on Windows 10)**

```
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\{version}
```

For example, mine is stored at

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\peter\GIMP\2.10\
```

Comment: Technically, the move it due to the new Gimp version (2.10 from 2.08) and not from a new Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest and fastest way is to open:

```
%APPDATA%\Gimp
```

You can just paste this in Win+R window. You can also use it in a `cmd` shell.

Note that `APPDATA` is a standard environment variable. I think it was even set on Windows 98, definetly on Windows XP and 7. The variable is automatically set for logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for linux are incorrect. I found the settings in `/home/user/.config/GIMP/2.10`. I copied this folder, then went to the new PC, deleted the same folder and then pasted the old folder in. Merging the new and old folders did **not** work.